# Changing view elements on action

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have been pondering for a while how to change the items on a UIView when you hit a button.  What I would like to do is have a UITextView with text on it, then hit a button and have a UIImage appear on the screen.  What I don't know how to do is how to put them together on the same view.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html addSubview?

Answer (score 0):

To clear the content of a `UIView` you need to do:

```
for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) {
     [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Than what you will need to do is just add the new `UIImage` to an `UIImageView` and than do:
`[view addSubView:myImageView];`

it should look like this:

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image name"]; // This is the image (UIImage)
UIImageView *myImageView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage]; // Insert the image to an UIImageView
[self.view addSubView:myImageView]; // Add the UIImageView to the view
```

running all of this code will:

- clear the view
- insert the image to the view

Answer (score 0):

1.Place an IBoutlet uiimageview on textview

2.at viewdidload set its property hidden YES

3.On button click method set its hidden property to NO

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image name"];
IBOutlet UIImageView *myImageView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
```

connect this to imageview on uitextview where you want to fix that image
In button method add this line

```
myImageView.hidden = NO;
```